# Set DataMembers as String.Empty

Tags: c#, datacontract

i have a dataContract with a few DataMembers as shown below. i wanna run each members of the DataContract and set it as string.Empty. all my dataMembers are of the type string. i dont know if its possible to do since by defalut the value is returned as Null. i want it to return string.Empty.
Thanks in advance

```
public class xyz
{
    [DataMember]
    public string a { get; set ; }

    [DataMember] 
    public string b { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string c { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string d { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string e { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `string` is a reference type. So it's default value would be null. Hence it's reasonable that the default value you get is null.

Now saying that you want to return it as `String.Empty` it depends on when you want that. Please be more specific, in order to post here some code that would meet that you want.

Comment: i wanna set it as string.Empty before i fetch its values from the database so that if i miss out on a few datamembers they can be sent as string.Empty instead of Null. im trying to run the members through a loop and access each of them and set them as string.empty

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on the shorthand property declaration, write it out in full and give a default value to each:

```
private string _a;

[DataMember]
public string a 
{ 
    get
    { 
        if(_a == null)
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
        return _a;
    }

    set
    {
        _a = value
    }
}
```

Comment: i wanna do this in my business layer rather than in the dataContract it self.

Comment: Why are you posting the DataContract code, then, when you want us to look at the client side code?

Comment: i haven written it yet. so i sent the dataContract for which i wanted it for.i didnt know how to get the job done.so...

Comment: I suggest you clarify what you're trying to do, then, before asking questions. There may turn out to be no good reason to make your strings empty rather than null.